# Draggable Slider Ruler in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Looking for a draggable (By draggable I mean scrolls on double click) ruler as the one shown in the link below.

https://www.ladderlife.com/apply#SW5zdXJlZFBlcnNvbi5IZWlnaHQ=

I would really appreciate if someone would help me get the library to achieve the same functionality

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  function getVal() {
    var p = $(".ladder").position().top;
    var r = 1;
    var h = $(".step").height();
    switch (true) {
      case (p > 18 && p < 60):
        r = 10;
        break;
      case (p > -22 && p < 17):
        r = 9;
        break;
      case (p > -55 && p < -21):
        r = 8;
        break;
      case (p > -92 && p < -54):
        r = 7;
        break;
      case (p > -130 && p < -92):
        r = 6;
        break;
      case (p > -166 && p < -130):
        r = 5;
        break;
      case (p > -200 && p < -166):
        r = 4;
        break;
      case (p > -238 && p < -200):
        r = 3;
        break;
      case (p > -272 && p < -238):
        r = 2;
        break;
      case (p < -272):
        r = 1;
        break;
    }
    return r;
  }
  $(".ladder").draggable({
    axis: "y",
    containment: [0, -300, 150, 60],
    drag: function(e, ui) {
      $(".value").val(getVal());
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-ladder {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.ui-ladder .step {
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.ui-ladder .marker {
  border-top: 2px solid rgba(255,0,0,0.65);
  position: absolute;
  top: 51px;
  width: 100%;
}

.ui-ladder .value {
  position: absolute;
  top: 41px;
  left: 118px;
  width: 1.5em;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.ui-ladder .arrow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid #ccc;
  margin-left: -10px;
  top: 42px;
  left: 118px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="ui-ladder ui-widget">
  <div class="ui-widget-content ladder" style="top: -145px">
    <div class="step">10</div>
    <div class="step">9</div>
    <div class="step">8</div>
    <div class="step">7</div>
    <div class="step">6</div>
    <div class="step">5</div>
    <div class="step">4</div>
    <div class="step">3</div>
    <div class="step">2</div>
    <div class="step">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="marker"></div>
  <div class="arrow"></div>
  <input class="value ui-widget-header" value="5" type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, what about sectioning the inner steps into inches. For example between 4 and 5 we get 11 more steps, basically 11 more steps in between the integers, so that I can have something like 4 ft and 11inc.

Regards

Comment: @KarueBensonKarue you didn't clarify that you wanted the exact same thing. I provided a basic example that you could start with. Please review: How do I ask a good question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry, I got it and I've improved, by the way, how were you able to get default position of the marker. I mean the draggable position, yours is dragged at a position where marker reads 5, how can I drag it programmatically to fit another marker position.

Comment: @KarueBensonKarue as you can see, the `marker` is held with absolute positioning, relative to the parent. Since the User drags the `ladder` on a Y Axis only, we look at the `top` value. The `top` value then relates to a specific value you want to represent. I did it  with a `switch()` but you can do lots of things, like using Modulus.

Comment: Wow! great, I have just realized the way you set default position by this `<div class="ui-widget-content ladder" style="top: -145px">`. I have adjusted the top position to fit my own specification. Thanks, Everything now works like a charm

Comment: This is my final work: https://jsfiddle.net/oseb59zw/. I have improved your code to a greater program. By the way, when I add HTML mark up above this code, the containment is being affected. Not sure how to solve that